# Buidling boost error: Name clash for '<pstage\lib>boost_system-vc120-mt-1_58.dll'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build, b2

I'm trying to build `boost` on windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 on 64bit system.

```
b2 toolset="msvc" address-model=64 -s ZLIB_SOURCE=C:\H\M\zlib --build-type=complete stage
```

Here is full output:

```
Performing configuration checks

    - symlinks supported       : no
    - junctions supported      : yes
    - hardlinks supported      : yes
    - arm                      : no
    - mips1                    : no
    - power                    : no
    - sparc                    : no
    - x86                      : yes
    - has_icu builds           : no
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - iconv (libc)             : no
    - iconv (separate)         : no
    - icu                      : no
    - icu (lib64)              : no
    - message-compiler         : yes
    - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes
    - compiler-supports-avx2   : yes
    - gcc visibility           : no
    - long double support      : yes
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
error: Name clash for '<pstage\lib>boost_system-vc120-mt-1_58.dll'
error:
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having
error: these incompabile properties:
error:
error:     -  <warnings>all
error:     -  <architecture>x86 <warnings>on
error:
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

What does it mean and how to resolve it?

*Thanks*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

builds if I add --without-context --without-coroutine to b2 options

Answer (score 6):

From the [Boost 1.58 beta release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html):

> **Important Note**
>
> There is a bug with the build scripts; you have to specify the
>   address-mode and architecture to b2. I used:
>
> `./b2 address-model=64 architecture=x86`
>
> to test this.

Adding these flags to the `b2` command solves the problem without having to exclude the `context` and `coroutine` libraries (handy if, say, you actually use these libraries, like I do!).

Naturally, if you're building 32-bit libraries, you want to add `address-model=32` instead.

Comment: even with the parameters it failed to compile on 1.69

Answer (score 2):

Did you get boost from git repository?

If so, I think the latest version available in git is broken. Today I tried to compile it too and if you would solve errors you mentioned, you will get another errors because of incomplete files in destination directories ([boost ptr_container library isn't installed after compilation from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346593/boost-ptr-container-library-isnt-installed-after-compilation-from-source))

The solution was download latest boost version from their site (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.57.0/). After that, compilation and installation works correctly

Comment: Yes I was trying to get git version with all the submodules. Will try stable this evening.

Comment: I did  `git co boost-1.56.0;`, then build with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using `variant=release,debug` command line argument, which was causing name collision.

I've added extra argument `--layout=tagged` and problem disappeared.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55214183/2338477

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have two version of g++ available in `$PATH`. Try running `where g++`. If you see two g++ then remove one from `$PATH`. And then start over all the build process again. That worked for me and