# boost ptr_container library isn't installed after compilation from source

Tags: c++, boost, boost-ptr-container

I have updated boost library from previous 1.54 (svn source) to 1.57 (git source). Although I used the same ./b2 params, destination directory doesn't contain `ptr_container` library.

Directory with cloned repository correctly contains ptr_container library on this path:

```
boost_git/libs/ptr_container
```

I'm building it with following command:

```
   ./b2 --install --prefix=$SHL_PATH/boost -sNO_BZIP2=1 -sNO_ZLIB runtime-link=shared link=shared -j2 install
```

but without success.

---

Edit:

It seems that problem occurs only when building from git. When I downloaded zip package from boost site, destination directory correctly contains ptr_container.

This is a git commands I'm using to get source code:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git boost_git
git checkout tags/boost-1.57.0
git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout tags/boost-1.57.0
```

I also tried to get latest boost version, but this version isn't usable at all. Directly after I executed ./b2, I'm getting weird error similar to this one: [Buidling boost error: Name clash for '<pstage\lib>boost_system-vc120-mt-1_58.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342524/buidling-boost-error-name-clash-for-pstage-libboost-system-vc120-mt-1-58-dll)

I will be grateful for any hints how to correctly get&install boost from git repository.

Comment: I tried to simplified b2 params but without difference. `./b2 --prefix=~/dev/boost`

Comment: It seems that more files and libraries are missing. For example in `exception/include` there is only half of original files ;-(

Comment: try `./b2 headers` that will force b2 to make symlinks

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost
git checkout boost-1.57.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
./bootstrap.sh
sudo ./b2 install
sudo ./b2 headers
```

As pointed out by [rivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156933/rivanov) in the comments, `./b2 headers` does the trick to include the header-only files in the installation dir.