# Boost build breaks: Name clash for '<pstage/lib>libboost_system.so.1.58.0'

Tags: boost

I'm trying to do a boost source build, via:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost
./bootstrap
./b2 link=shared threading=multi variant=release --without-mpi
```

This chokes with the following error message:

```
error: Name clash for '<pstage/lib>libboost_system.so.1.58.0'
error: 
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having 
error: these incompabile properties:
error: 
error:     -  none
error:     -  <address-model>64 <architecture>x86
error: 
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these 
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

This occurs on both the `develop` and `master` branch. What can be done to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to build using the suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27885628/200985 . I'm compiling branch `boost-1.57.0`, and I started compiling branch `boost-1.56.0`, and it got past this point, too. To sum up, I ran

```
git co boost-1.57.0;
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/home/me/builds/development;
./b2 --prefix=/home/me/builds/development -j9 --without-context --without-coroutine;
```

Comment: I guess that gets me around the compilation problem, but I just don't understand why no one knows how to build the entire boost library. I'd prefer not to do this.

Answer (score 13):

From the [Boost 1.58 beta release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html):

> **Important Note**
>
> There is a bug with the build scripts; you have to specify the
>   address-mode and architecture to b2. I used:
>
> `./b2 address-model=64 architecture=x86`
>
> to test this.

Adding these flags to the `b2` command solves the problem without having to exclude the `context` and `coroutine` libraries (handy if, say, you actually use these libraries, like I do!).

Naturally, if you're building 32-bit libraries, you want to add `address-model=32` instead.

Comment: So this differs from the previous answer by `--address-model` vs. `address-model`?

Comment: @NickThompson: `--address-model` and `--architecture` don't appear to do anything - the correct way to specify those options is without the dashes. (That would explain why adding the options with dashes had no effect!)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the current git master.

As a workaround, explicitly state the address-model and architecture options on the command line:

```
./b2 link=shared threading=multi variant=release --without-mpi address-model=64 architecture=x86
```

Comment: I ran a 'git pull' and tried this, but it still came up with the same error message for me . . .

Comment: It should be `address-model=64`, not `--address-model=64` (i.e. without the leading double-dashes).