# How to use boost 1.63 library in c++ code blocks windows?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, codeblocks

I'm trying to work with the boost library in code:blocks IDE over windows.
The purpose is using the Dynamic Biteset.

Manged to use this tutorial to let the code:blocks find boost:
http://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/configure-codeblocks-boost-libraries-windows-linux/

Found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wCA124D3rg#t=324.174678
According to it, at first there's a need to run the bootstrap.
Managed to do so after installing Visual Studio Community 2015.
But couldn't continue to the next stage: running the bootstrap with minGW.
Used these instructions:
[Building boost 1.61.0 with MinGW 5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103244/building-boost-1-61-0-with-mingw-5-3-0)
Than completed the above youtube tutorial.

dynamic_biteset I get an error about:

## include BOOST_USER_CONFIG (which seems to be missing)

in the config.hpp

Any idea how to work with boost on windows machine?

Comment: Thanks! Found out how to search, edited the question (including a llink to a search tutorial) but still getting an error in the config.hpp file.

Comment: You may want to try https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg to install Boost for VS2015. Follow the instructions on their readme, then install boost via `.\vcpkg install boost`. If you want to use MinGW for C::B then try "this guy"'s MinGW distro: https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: Yes! The VCPKG works great (I tested in Visual Studio), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These instructions build boost v1.63 using the compiler packaged with codeblocks v17.12 on windows ( The latest boost version does not support the codeblocks v17 compiler )

1 Download and unzip boost_1_63_0.7z to boost_folder\v1_63\ ( Here and below select an appropriate path for boost_folder on your system )

2 Open cmd window

3 Type PATH = PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks17\MinGW\bin

4 Type cd boost_folder\v1_63\tools\build

5 Type bootstrap gcc

6 Type .\b2.exe install toolset=gcc --prefix=boost_folder\v1_63\b2_for_mingw

7 Type cd boost_folder\v1_63

8 Type PATH=%PATH%;boost_folder\v1_63\b2_for_mingw

9 Type b2 -j4 --toolset=gcc stage ( Assumes you have a CPU with 4 threads )

10 Set codeblocks global variables as:

```
boost         boost_folder\v1_63
boost.include boost_folder\v1_63
boost.lib     boost_folder\v1_63\stage\lib
```

11 You will have to link with whatever specific boost library your project needs.  The library names have the pattern `boost_system-mgw51-mt-1_63`

Comment: Thanks @ravenspoint, ended up using boost on visual studio after installing it using vcpkg.